# Trying to get a high output from a pulsing input

Tags: digital-logic

I'm still rather new to electronics so any easy-to-understand answer if there is one would be neat.
I have a 555 timer pulsing a (let's say) 5Kh signal from its output. I'm trying to figure out how to take that signal and while it's pulsing get something (another IC I guess) to output a constant high signal and when no pulse is detected to output a low.
output of the timer is about 5v.

Comment: You can use another 555 for that. The datasheets usually have examples for detecting a missing pulse. Or use microcontroller. It's hard to suggest as you don't say why you want to detect a signal and what happens when it is not detected.

Comment: How long should the missing pulse detection circuit wait before it decides that there is a missing pulse or no pulses coming along? It's kHz and not Kh BTW and, we put a gap between 5 and kHz like this: 5 kHz.

Answer (score 1):

This should be relatively easy to achieve with just a capacitor and a resistor, a so-called RC network.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fViVLE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically, the RC time constant needs to be a few times longer than the time period of the 5 kHz signal, which is equal to 1/5000Hz=0.2ms.

Time constant is simply calculated by T = RC = 1000 ohms x 1 nF = 1 ms, which is 5 time constants of the signal, and should give a DC voltage at the output whenever there is the 5 kHz signal coming from the 555 (the generator).

You can also make it longer, by using 10 nF capacitor for example. Larger capacitor gives you a "cleaner" DC output, with a smaller ripple, but also takes longer to reach the full DC voltage at the beginning, and to drop its output to zero once the 5 kHz signal is off, however it shouldn't be an issue if it's not longer than a few milliseconds, depending on the exact purpose of your circuit.

Comment: I'll give this a shot thanks. might make a tweak here and there because like I said in a previous comment the circuit is a little more complicated than I actually originally said. I made one with a basic simulation program (everycircuit) but it just bombed out when I started it and in my limited understanding it shouldn't have done that so I'm going to prototype it anyhow.

Comment: If you want better help, you need to provide more information about your circuit requirements. And don't be afraid of experimenting, it's what helps you understand circuits and get better at it. You will no doubt make mistakes, don't let that discourage you, it's part of the process. Even knowledgeable and experienced engineers sometimes have problems with simple circuits. You can add a transistor to this RC circuit to reduce the load on it and amplify its output.

Comment: The whole idea of the circuit is a water leveling sensing circuit but with an oscillating probe as to avoid the corrosion or buildup problem on the terminals. I've built one from another source using a NAND logic gate and it works but it bugs me. I understood the idea that the one gate supplies a pulse at one terminal and the other picks it up and I used that idea to see if I could supply a pulse using a 555 timer on one terminal and I'm trying to pick it up with the other side. I've done that so far but I seem to run into a problem picking it up, I'm thinking now about using a darlington pair